# Onclick event doesnt get property value but shows on the console the tag with all its properties

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Ok so I am trying to get the name of a component so I can handle it my own way to change the state. However, when I try getting this component name from e.currentTarget.name it shows **'undefined'**. But when I console.log(e.currentTarget) it shows the whole element I am aiming for

*I have tried using both console.log(e.currentTarget) and console.log(e.currentTarget.name). The former shows the element like I mentioned above and the latter shows "undefined"*

**This is what I get when I am using e.currentTarget**

```
<div role="button" class="MuiChip-root-455 MuiChip-colorSecondary-457 MuiChip-clickable-458 MuiChip-clickableColorSecondary-460" tabindex="0" name="status"><span class="MuiChip-label-474">Chip One</span></div>
```

this is the code for the click event:

```
toggleColumn = (e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
  } 

<Grid item md={4} className={classes.chipWrapper}>
  <Chip
    label="Chip One"
     name="status"
     color={color}
     variant={variant}
     onClick={this.toggleColumn}
     className={classes.chipButton}
   />
</Grid>
```

As you can see, it has name='status' on it.

I am trying to get this property value but I can't

Comment: Use event.target.name instead of event.currentTarget.name like wise to get value event.target.value

Comment: if I use event.target it doesnt target the element I want

Comment: Can you post your click event code!?

Comment: Sure. its probably working though, since it's getting the currentTarget tag elements.

Comment: Are you sure you want to get that property by reading the DOM? what about something like this `onClick={() => this.toggleColumn('status')}`. name is probably undefined because you should use DOM api to get the value, something like   `e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name')`

Comment: Try: `e.currentTarget.current.name`.

Comment: I think accessing the `name` attribute is only possible on inputs tags - I don't have checked for docs. But in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrxvpzzo2z) you can see the difference. I don't know more of your app but I would also use an arrow function as Kunukn mentioned.

Comment: thank you @Kunukn it worked!